# How can I export GridView to MS Access in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to export grid to MS Access in C#

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
String accessConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\\...\\test.accdb;"; 
String sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["College"].ConnectionString; 
SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
adapter1.Fill(dtFillGrid); 
ADOX.Catalog catalog = new ADOX.Catalog(); 
catalog.Create(accessConnectionString); 
OleDbConnection accessConnection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(); 
command.Connection = accessConnection; 
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
accessConnection.Open(); 
foreach (DataTable table in dtFillGrid.Rows) { 
    String columnsCommandText = "(";
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns) { 
        String columnName = column.ColumnName; 
        String dataTypeName = column.DataType.Name; 
        String sqlDataTypeName = getSqlDataTypeName(dataTypeName); 
        columnsCommandText += "[" + columnName + "] " + sqlDataTypeName + ","; 
    }   
    columnsCommandText = columnsCommandText.Remove(columnsCommandText.Length - 1);   
    columnsCommandText += ")";
    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + table.TableName + columnsCommandText; 
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
//This loop fills the database with all information 
foreach (DataTable table in dtFillGrid.Rows) { 
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) { 
        String commandText = "INSERT INTO " + table.TableName + " VALUES (";
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray) { 
            commandText += "'" + item.ToString() + "',";
        } 
        commandText = commandText.Remove(commandText.Length - 1); 
        commandText += ")"; 
        command.CommandText = commandText; command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
} 
accessConnection.Close();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: web grid or win forms grid?

Comment: yes i try some code like this :
 
String accessConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\...\\test.accdb;";
        String sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["College"].ConnectionString;

 SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();

 adapter1.Fill(dtFillGrid);
  ADOX.Catalog catalog = new ADOX.Catalog();
        catalog.Create(accessConnectionString);
OleDbConnection accessConnection = new OleDbConnection(accessConnectionString);

Comment: OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = accessConnection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        accessConnection.Open();
  foreach (DataTable table in dtFillGrid.Rows)
        {
            String columnsCommandText = "(";

Comment: foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                String columnName = column.ColumnName;
                String dataTypeName = column.DataType.Name;
                String sqlDataTypeName = getSqlDataTypeName(dataTypeName);
                columnsCommandText += "[" + columnName + "] " + sqlDataTypeName + ",";
            }
            columnsCommandText = columnsCommandText.Remove(columnsCommandText.Length - 1);
            columnsCommandText += ")";

Comment: command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " + table.TableName + columnsCommandText;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

Comment: //This loop fills the database with all information
        foreach (DataTable table in dtFillGrid.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                String commandText = "INSERT INTO " + table.TableName + " VALUES (";

Comment: foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    commandText += "'" + item.ToString() + "',";
                }
                commandText = commandText.Remove(commandText.Length - 1);
                commandText += ")";

                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        accessConnection.Close();

Comment: Edit your question with relevant code instead of posting it here in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create the MDB database, create the table(s) you want using sql, then at runtime bind the gridview, or loop through the results and do a batch import.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677200(v=vs.85).aspx

```
using ADOX;  // add a COM reference to "Microsoft ADO Ext. x.x for DDL and Security" 

static void CreateMdb(string fileNameWithPath)
{
  ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
  string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5";
  cat.Create(String.Format(connstr, fileNameWithPath));
  cat = null;
}
```

Comment: here when I am using 
ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
its show some error like:
The Type or namespace ADOX could not be found

Comment: Yes I tell you to all of you that we don't need to export data by gridview to MS Access , we can do this directly create database in MS Access using C#

Answer (score 1):

if you dont have problem with payement you can use 'Spire doc' to save datagrid into msAccess like so :

```
private void btnExportToAccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport accessExport = new              
    Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport();
    accessExport.DataSource = Spire.DataExport.Common.ExportSource.DataTable;
    accessExport.DataTable = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    accessExport.DatabaseName = @"..\..\ToMdb.mdb";
    accessExport.TableName = "ExportFromDatatable";
    accessExport.SaveToFile();
}
```

and [Here](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.DataExport/Spire.DataExport-Program-Guide/How-to-Export-Data-into-MS-Access-in-C.html) a link where you can find more clarification

Answer (score 0):

Here I am not export gridview in MS Access but I made a database in MS Access by using C# with the help of this code:

```
    ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
    ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();

    //Create the table and it's fields. 
    table.Name = "Table1";
    table.Columns.Append("PartNumber", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 6); // text[6]
    table.Columns.Append("AnInteger", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, 10); // Integer 
    try
    {
        cat.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=d:/m2.accdb;" + "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5");
        cat.Tables.Append(table);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;" + "Data Source=d:/m2.accdb");
       conn.Open();

             OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
             cmd.Connection = conn;

             cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1([PartNumber],[AnInteger]) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName)";

             cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "neha";

             cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 20;

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();                                 

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    cat = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tell you to all of you that we don't need to export data by gridview to MS Access , we can do this directly create database in MS Access using C#